# Is it okay store PhoneGapp app settings on localStorage?

Tags: cordova, local-storage

Is `localStorage` safe to store data to? For example, settings. I've found it especially useful and easy to use with it's key-value pair system. However, upon seeing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282032/), it made me double think about using `localStorage`. I don't want the settings stored in the cache and is readily deletable by some 3rd party app (cache cleaners).

As an additional note, where is the `localStorage` found in my Android phone?

Answer (score 1):

I use localStorage and I haven't any problem yet.

See more info: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

On mobile phone you don't have any choice to see localStorage but if you open app in your brower, you could check data on your localStorage with programmer tools.

On other hand, I think that app localStorage has the same behavior of localStorage on the website.