# Cordova 2.0 iOS Persistent Storage Strategy

Tags: ios, cordova, persistent-storage

Has Cordova 2.0 resolved the iOS persistent storage issue? (Web storage was moved to cache directory in iOS 5.1x which broke a lot of apps in Cordova)

I wonder if the Storage API is safe to use for persistent storage...
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Or is the SQLite Plugin now safe...
https://github.com/chbrody/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Or is the only really "safe" method to use the File API...
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

**More Details**
My app will write several hundred records (mostly integers) into a few tables. Data will be captured offline and eventually need to be synced to an online db. The complexity is comparable to a typical small dynamic corporate website, without all the heavy TEXT. So... an SQL like setup would be ideal.

**EDIT**
I went with the above mentioned SQLLitePlugin which worked as advertised. It's been 2 years so not sure what new options are available now.

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer?

Comment: thank you. any reason you choose that over the built in `window.openDatabase`?

Comment: Back when I wrote the app, SQLite Plugin was the only option that: 1. Did not have a size limit and 2. would not be automatically erased by iOS. Local storage was moved to a temp location in 5.x. It's possible the limitations I ran into have been lifted... [check this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664392/phonegap-ios-5-1-and-localstorage)