# PhoneGap iOS 7 and localStorage

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, local-storage, web-storage

I’m currently building a PhoneGap 3.3.0 iOS application which uses Ember.js/EmberData with a LocalStorage adapter to persist data. After reading some articles [like this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664392/phonegap-ios-5-1-and-localstorage) I’d like to know how the LocalStorage data is handled by iOS 7. Is it stored permanently or still stored in a cache folder which is note backed up to iTunes/iCloud? Unfortunately, the [PhoneGap documentation on LocalStorage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) only refers to the official W3C spec.

The only thing said about the handling of the web storage is a [description of a flag](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html#The%20config.xml%0AFile) in the `config.xml`:

> BackupWebStorage (string, either none, local, or the default cloud):
>   Set to cloud to allow web storage data to backup via iCloud. Set to
>   local to allow only local backups via iTunes sync. Set to none prevent
>   web storage backups.
>
> `<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="local"/>`

The [Safari Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH6-SW3) also don’t mention the internals of the LocalStorage implementation and how it is treated in a App update cycle.

I’d really like to know how the LocalStorage data is handled by iOS 7, and maybe if there is a doc on this that I’ve missed, then can someone please point it out to me.

Comment: Did you find out if this issue has been fixed?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't found any further information ...

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "does local storage persist after app update cycle" I can say yes based on experience [with my app](http://www.brian-fitzgerald.net/i-ching).

I have set

```
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="local" />
```

in the config.xml. I store a journal of I-Ching readings to local storage and have now been through two app update cycles with no user data loss. I don't have any further documentation on the mechanics though.