# Local storage not working for sencha touch app

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I developed a sencha touch app where it stores user credentials in local storage of browser for auto login purpose(I know it's not secure but for testing purpose I need it to store here) it works fine in web browser.
but when it is converted in to native mobile app using phone gap build and installed in iphone, auto login is failing and user is redirected to login page every time. is there any other way to achieve auto login in sencha touch?

Comment: Does the manual login work?

Comment: did you try to debug and see if the store exist at the time of auto login?

Comment: Gautham if you can share the code that what you tried then someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through these link.

[Phonegap iOS 5.1 and localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664392/phonegap-ios-5-1-and-localstorage)

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?188163-iOS-5.1-Native-and-LocalStorage-(And-SQLite)